# Processing and counting words from large JSON file from Twitter into Pandas DF

Tags: python, json, twitter, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a small script that works and gives me the exact output I want on a small .json file of sample tweets. Here's the desired process:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import string

statuses = []

for line in open('/Users/Me/MyTweets.json'):
try: 
statuses.append(json.loads(line))
except:
pass

times = [status['created_at'] for status in statuses]

b = map(lambda x: x[:16],times)
unique_minutes = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(b))


count_by_date_master = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word', 'counter', 'date'])

for i in range(0,len(unique_minutes)): 
timenow = unique_minutes[i]
status_texts= [status['text'] 
             for status in statuses if status['created_at'].startswith(timenow)] 

stopwordlist = stopwords.words()
words_split = [ w 
      for t in status_texts 
          for w in t.split() if not w.lower() in stopwordlist]
words = [x.lower() for x in words_split]
words =  [''.join(x for x in aword if x not in string.punctuation) for aword in words]
words = [x for x in words if x != 'amp']
words = [x for x in words if x != 'rt']
words = [x for x in words if x != '']
words = [x for x in words if not x.startswith("htt")]
for item in [words]:
    c = Counter(item) 
d = {w:f for w, f in Counter(words).most_common()}
counter_df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['word', 'counter'])
#remove spaces from date to use as a time marker in pandas
z = [''.join(e for e in row if e.isalnum()) for row in unique_minutes]
l = [z[i]]
date_l = l * len(counter_df)
date_a = numpy.asarray(date_l, dtype=None, order=None)
date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_a, columns=['date'])
pieces = [counter_df, date_df]
count_by_date = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1)
count_by_date_master = count_by_date_master.append(count_by_date)
count_by_date_master #final df for analysis
```

So this gives me counts per word for blocks of tweets per minute. This is exactly what I need. The problem is that it works fine on 8k tweets, but I've tried to run this on a 250MB json file and unsurprisingly it's taking forever to run.

I have tried experimenting with the multiprocessing library after splitting the file first like this:

```
awk 'NR%20000==1 { file = FILENAME "_" sprintf("%04d", NR+19) } { print > file }' /Users/Me/Tweetsplit/MyTweets.json
```

and then including this at the start of the script:

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import sys
def input_worker(file,out_q):
```

with this at the end to go through the newly split files with the intention of running the desired process against each file at a time, then pulling all the output together into a pandas dataframe:

```
out_q.put(count_by_date)
out_q.task_done()


out_q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

workers = []
for file in os.listdir('/Users/Me/Tweetsplit/'):
    file = '/Users/Me/Tweetsplit/' + file
    worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=input_worker, args=(file,out_q))
    workers.append(worker)
    worker.start()

count_by_date_master = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word', 'counter', 'date'])

while True:
    result = out_q.get()
    count_by_date_master.append(result)


for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

However this is also running indefinitely, like there needs an explicit exit or .close command somewhere.

Can anyone with a better knowledge of multiprocessing and such give me some advice? Or a suggestion of an alternative would be great too. It would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hi. You say it is 'running forever', but do you know if it is still progressing? Have you checked status of your machine, I.e. memory, CPU, disk while it is running? If you do multiprocessing you need to know how much of your resources you are using... Anyway I would 1st try to figure out what's happening with the single process. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at my question. 'Running forever' = the single process was going for over 2 hours and didn't complete so I killed it. I'm using ipython notebook and to be honest, I don't know how to check the machine status. I figured splitting the task into smaller parts, which I already know will work as individual bitesize pieces was why I hopped straight to multiprocessing. I'll check it out, perhaps run it for longer or see if I can run it on a better machine.

Comment: You're welcome! Depends on your platform, is it Windows, Mac? But just use the avail process monitor. 1st look at the overall state and then to the iphyton process. Maybe you need to give it more memory or something like that. I'll check later today.

Comment: As for the process running for two hours, do you know what was the state when you killed it? Have you made calculations from the small file timing to figure out how long it should take for the long one?

Comment: The following two links might be useful: [ipython profiler](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html) and [guide to python performance](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/). Before going to a multiprocess I'd suggest to analyze the single process 1st (unless you had a good hint on where the problem is). If you provide an example json file I might be able to give something closer to answer. Hope it helps anyway.